# how do i bootstrap cfengine on ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server

i'm trying to use the cfengine version in the ubuntu repositories rather than download the cfengine-community repository, because the ubuntu repository has binaries for armhf.  however, i'm having a difficult time bootstrapping.  on the cfengine-community version of cfengine, (and according to any available documentation) running

```
cf-agent --bootstrap --policy-server <ip.of.server>
```

would make the client machine pull in updates from the policy server.  on ubuntu, that same command does absolutely nothing.  any ideas?

Comment: okay, apparently the version in the repositories (3.15) can't have a policy server set.

Comment: I recommend the packages from the CFEngine public repository. See http://cfengine.com/cfengine-linux-distros

Answer (score 0):

What version of CFEngine?

cf-promises -V

Please run cf-agent with the verbose option paste all output.